# Add data to trigger from the last insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am faced with the following situation:

[image]

I created a trigger which reacts on insert to the third table. When I insert any data (for example `1 1 2`), last number should be subtracted from the Amount of stock column from cell, which has necessary `ID Product` (as it's shown on picture). But how can I understand which row was the last added? I thought firstly to do it by select, but it seems impossible. And now I think that it's possible to do it with the help of cursor, but it doesn't seem as the best variant. Is there a better variant how can I do it?

Here's my code of trigger, but it only subtracts 1 from the 1st product each time, unfortunately:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AmountInsert ON Amount
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product
    SET Amount_On_Stock =
     (SELECT Amount_On_Stock FROM Product
    WHERE ID_Product = 1) - 1
    WHERE ID_Product = 1
END
```

Comment: To know which row was the last added you either need a datetime column, or you need an incrementing integer column.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, updated the question

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables as that is how you determine what rows to update.

Comment: And what happens if a purchase is reversed? A sudden loophole in your warehouse? You'd be very likely better off with a table that logs what goes in for whatever reason and what goes out (or draw that from multiple tables like purchases, discards, deliveries, returns, etc.) and query your stocked quantities by taking the sum (with the outs negated of course). For convenience you can write a view for that. Like that your safe to always have accurate figures and also keep the complete history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that in a trigger in SQL Server you are provided with an [`inserted` pseudo-table and a `deleted` pseudo-table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017). You use these tables to determine what changes have occurred.

I think the following trigger accomplishes what you are looking for - the comments explain the logic.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.AmountInsert ON dbo.Amount
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  set nocount on;

  update P set
    -- Adjust the stock level by the amount of the latest insert
    Amount_On_Stock = coalesce(Amount_On_Stock) - I.Amount
  from dbo.Product P
  inner join (
    -- We need to group by ID_Product in case the same product appears in the insert multiple times
    select ID_Product, sum(Amount) Amount
    from Inserted
    group by ID_Product
    -- No need to update is net change is zero
    having sum(Amount) <> 0
  ) I
  on I.ID_Product = P.ID_Product;
END
```