# The aggregate expression cannot be used in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following tables in my database:

[image]

The first table is named `Amount`, second `Product`, third `Purchase`.

And I should to create the trigger on insert to amount table. For example, I'll insert the following values: 4, 1, 10, where 4 is `id_purchase`, 1 is `id_product` and 4 is amount of this products. And trigger should subtract this amount from `Amount_On_Stock`. In my example, it should be: was 48, became 38.

Here's the code of my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AmountInsert ON Amount
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product
    SET Amount_On_Stock = (
            SELECT 
                Amount_On_Stock 
            FROM Product
            WHERE ID_Product = (
                SELECT 
                    MAX(ID_Product) 
                FROM Purchase
                WHERE ID_Purchase = (
                    SELECT 
                        MAX(ID_Purchase) 
                    FROM Purchase
                )
            )
        )-(
            SELECT 
                Amount 
            FROM AMOUNT
            WHERE ID_Product = (
                SELECT 
                    MAX(ID_Product) 
                FROM Purchase
                WHERE ID_Purchase = (
                    SELECT 
                        MAX(ID_Purchase) 
                    FROM Purchase
                )
            )
            )
END
```

But when I try to create this trigger I have the following error:

> The aggregate expression cannot be used in the WHERE clause unless it
>   is contained in a subquery of the HAVING clause or in the select list,
>   and the column being aggregated is not an external reference.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158300/how-to-add-data-to-trigger-from-the-last-insert), which already has a possible answer? You're still not using the `inserted` or `deleted` pseudo-tables.

Comment: That code is unreadable. All those subqueries and all lined up together you can't tell where one ends and the next one begins. And there are multiple subqueries to get the same value over and over. You should learn how joins work. This is way overly complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add data to trigger from the last insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158300/how-to-add-data-to-trigger-from-the-last-insert)

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger looks nothing like a SQL Server trigger.  I would expect your trigger to look more like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AmountInsert ON Amount AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
        SET Amount_On_Stock = p.Amount_On_Stock - i.amount
        FROM Product p JOIN
             inserted i
             ON p.ID_Product = i.ID_Product;
END;
```

However, this will not do the right thing if you have multiple `insert`s on the same product at the same time.  To handle that you need aggregation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AmountInsert ON Amount AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
        SET Amount_On_Stock = p.Amount_On_Stock - i.amount
        FROM Product p JOIN
             (SELECT i.ID_Product, SUM(i.amount) as amount
              FROM inserted i
              GROUP BY i.ID_Product
             ) i
             ON p.ID_Product = i.ID_Product;
END;
```

Comment: Pretty much the answer I gave him when he first asked this question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158300/how-to-add-data-to-trigger-from-the-last-insert